# Showing submitted values into database into next php page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a **verify** page for my reservation website but I can't show only specific data from picking the specific id.

For example, I submitted a new customer and it generated an ID = 1. Then the form will take me to another PHP page and I want it to show the name of the customer I just submitted by choosing it's specific ID (which is 1 or whatever id was generated from before).

Here's my **first submit form**:

```
  <form action="menuactions/temporestoaction.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
   <label class="control-label">First Name:</label>
     <input class="form-control" placeholder="John" type="text" name="first_name" required autofocus/>
     <br />
   <label>Last Name:</label>
   <input class="form-control" placeholder="Doe" type="text" name="last_name" required/>
   <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

and this is the **temporestoaction.php** which will submit all the values into mysql database:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))   {
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "records";

 //Form Inputs to Db
 $foodid = $_POST['foodid'];
 $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
 $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
 // Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `temporesto` ( first_name, last_name)
 VALUES ( '$firstname', '$lastname')";
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
 header('Location: ../temporesto.php?id='.$row['food_id'].'');
 exit();
 } else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
 }

 mysqli_close($conn);
 }
?>
```

Which will then redirect to a new PHP page, the **temporesto.php**:

```
<?php 
     include 'menuactions/temporestopick.php';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
         ?>

    <input type='hidden' value=" <?php echo $_GET['food_id'];?>" name="iduse">
    <label class="control-label">First Name: <h2><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></h2></label>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" />
 <br />
 <label class="control-label">Last Name: <h2><?php echo $row['last_name'];?></h2></label>
 <?php          
 }
 ?>
```

The problem I have with this is that it shows all of the values submitted instead of a specific one, [see this image for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxPO0.png)

P.S
**temporestopick.php** is using `"SELECT * FROM temporesto";`

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the whole code inside **temporestoaction.php** and added this:

```
<html>

<body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      //Form Inputs to Db
    $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $eventdate = $_POST['eventdate'];
    $eventtime = $_POST['eventtime1'];
    $eventhours = $_POST['eventhours1'];
    $packages = $_POST['packages'];
    $food = $_POST['food'];
    $prices = $_POST['price-total'];
    $treats = $_POST['treats'];
    $chkfood = "";
    $chktreats = "";

    foreach($food as $chkfood1)  
       {  
          $chkfood.= $chkfood1.",";  
       }   
    foreach($treats as $chktreats1)  
       {  
          $chktreats.= $chktreats1.", ";  
       }   
    ?>
    <label><h2>NAME: <?php echo $firstname . " " . $lastname; ?></h2>        </label>
            <br/>
            <label><h2>Contact: <?php echo $contact; ?></h2></label>
            <br/>
            <label><h2>Food: <?php echo $chkfood; ?></h2></label>
            <br/>
            <label><h2>Event Date: <?php echo $eventdate; ?></h2></label>
            <br/>
            <label><h2>Event Time: <?php echo $eventtime; ?></h2></label>
            <br/>
            <label><h2>Event Hours: <?php echo $eventhours; ?></h2></label>
            <br/>
            <label><h2>Packages: <?php echo $packages; ?></h2></label>
            <br/>
            <label><h2>Food: <?php echo $chkfood; ?></h2></label>
            <br/>
            <label><h2>Prices: <?php echo $prices; ?></h2></label>
            <br/>
            <label><h2>Treats: <?php echo $chktreats; ?></h2></label>    
        </body> 
        <?php   
       }
        ?>
    </html>
```

With this code, it takes all the inputs from my **submit form** and transfers it into the next page for verifying.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display a verify page before you process form, then I don't see the need to save first into the database. You can simply post all form values from your form and they would be contained in your `$_POST` which is an array. You then sanitize all inputs, loop through to get all their values then display them for verification. If all is okay, you sanitize again then insert into your database.

In case you are a little lost, you can do the following.

- Submit your form with the values filled to your action page.
- In your action page, sanitize all received values from the form.
- You can use `extract($_POST);` to get the values of your form fields into strings.
- Display for viewing and confirmation then submit values to database after sanitizing.

Sample:
**process.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   //sanitize your $_POST values
   foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        $_POST[$key] = sanitize($value);
        //You can out errors from empty fields here if you want
     }
     //extract $_POST values into strings
     extract($_POST);
     /*
     If your form has something like input name="fname" when you extract you will get the value for name as $name
      You can then echo Name: $fname
     */
      $values = <<<EOD
      Name: {$name}
      Email: {$email}
EOD;
}
```

I hope you are able to get on with this. After this stage of verification then you can save to database to avoid you saving unwanted data into your database.

Comment: Having an error:  `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sanitize()`

Comment: function sanitize() should be your function to clean your inputs and ensure you get the good needed values and not injected or dirty values.